# Interpreting a main effect, in the presence of an interaction

Tags: anova, mixed-model, interaction

In my analysis I have subjects whose blood pressure is measured across time, for two dose conditions (control and drug).

I have used a linear mixed effect model and plotted best-fit lines of the BP responses across time. Shown in below image.

Essentially in all subjects measured, the 'slope' of these lines is more steeply negative for the drug condition, slowly decaying towards control levels - however, throughout the period measured, the drug condition remains higher compared to the control condition.

My analysis seems to reflect this, with an interaction of dose x time, but also a main effect of dose.

Am I justified in the following interpretation: that the effect of dose decreased over time (interaction), but across the period measured, the effect of dose was to increase blood pressure values.

Many thanks.[image: Plot of subjects' data across time for two conditions]

Answer (score 2):

Note, that your main effect of dose refers to the effect of dose, when the variable time = 0. Thus, assuming that both the main effect dose and the interaction of dose x time are statistically significant, a more precise interpretation would be: There is a statistically significant effect of dose at time = 0 but this effect decreases significantly over time.

Just from your model output, you cannot conclude whether the dose effect is significant for other values of time. You could, however, change the centering of your time variable to accomplish this. You might want to adjust your p-values for multiple comparisons in this case.

Comment: Hi thank you but I am a bit confused - I thought a main effect applies to the whole time period? That was always my interpretation of a main effect?

Comment: This is true, when the interaction is not included in the model. However, when you include the interaction, the main effect terms represent conditional (instead of marginal) effects. See [here](https://www.theanalysisfactor.com/interpreting-lower-order-coefficients-when-the-model-contains-an-interaction/) for a more detailed explanation.